# Splitting out [nimble] BLE stack from nimble tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [nimble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nimble) tag (grails plugin) is being used often for NimBLE (Apache Bluetooth Low Energy stack) and sometimes Nimble Streamer(a transcoding & transmuxing server) and sometimes several other things. Should we make a new tag, nimble-ble-stack, and submit edits?

Quick survey of questions tagged with [nimble]: 34

- Grails Plugin: 4
- NimBLE: 3 (but I suggested removing the [nimble] tag from some before asking this question, many more are not tagged as well)
- R-NIMBLE: 2
- Nimble Streamer: 4
- Node Nimble: 4
- nim-lang's package manager: 1
- Quick/Nimble(Swift&ObjC): 9
- Restivus Nimble: 1
- nimble.com CRM: 3

Comment: I'd suggest probably also renaming to [tag:nimble-grails] and deleting the ambiguous [tag:nimble] After, of course, all the different uses have been resolved. I'm seeing quite a few other uses of this tag like the [R nimble package](https://r-nimble.org/).

Comment: Stack be [nimble], stack be quick, can stack split tag for NimBLE stack?